# load an xml file using javascript i

Tags: javascript, html, xml

i am trying to upload an xml file using javascript. my javascript code is given below:

```
var xmlDoc =null;
var abc = new Array();
if (window.ActiveXObject){
    xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
}
else if (document.implementation.createDocument){
    xmlDoc=document.implementation.createDocument("","",null);
}
else{
    alert('Browser cannot handle this script');
}
if (xmlDoc!=null){
    xmlDoc.async=false;
    xmlDoc.load("employee.xml");
    var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("EMP");
    for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
    { 
        abc[0] = x[0].getElementsByTagName("ID")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        document.write("a is "+abc[0]);
        abc[1] = x[0].getElementsByTagName("ID1")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        document.write("<br>b is "+abc[1]);
    }
}
```

and my xml file is:

```
<EMPLOYEE> 
<EMP> 
    <ID>10.99</ID> 
    <ID1>20.54</ID1> 
</EMP> 
</EMPLOYEE>
```

the code is working properly in IE as well as firefox but in Google Chrome, it is not showing anything. can some one tell me where i am wrong or how to correct it.

Comment: Please add the source code of your XML file not only the copied content from viewer.

Comment: the dashboard was not accepting my xml file thats why i have to remove the <> the xml data is <EMPLOYEE>
<EMP>
<ID>10.99</ID>
<ID1>20.54</ID1>
</EMP>
</EMPLOYEE>

Comment: You have to intend the lines with the XML code. Then it will be formated and accepted by SO.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the XML file in Chrome you need to execute a GET. For security reasons you cannot load it in a straight forward manner from the file system. Here's code:

```
var xmlhttp = new window.XMLHttpRequest(); 
xmlhttp.open("GET", xmlsrc, false); 
xmlhttp.send(null); 
var xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement;
```

Comment: @user1852933 What did you use for xmlsrc?

Comment: i have used my xml file name i.e. emp.xml

Comment: @user1852933 Debug using the networking tab to see whether the request retrieves anything because it probably doesn't.